# How can I colour my sketch using pen tool within the limited edge boundaries using sobel edge detection/canny edge detection in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift4, gpuimage

I am using `GPUImage` to detect the edge and applying GPUImageSobelEdgeDetectionFilter or GPUImageCannyEdgeDetectionFilter . Now my requirement is:

How can I take the coordinate points from that image so that I can make drawing within the closed boundaries.

***Detect Edges from Image***

```
   var image_p: GPUImagePicture?
   var filterImageview: UIImageView! // to display images

   let inputImage = filterImageview.image
    if let anImage = inputImage {
        image_p = GPUImagePicture(image: anImage)
    }

    let filter1 = GPUImageSobelEdgeDetectionFilter()//GPUImageCannyEdgeDetectionFilter()
    image_p?.addTarget(filter1)
    image_p?.processImage()

    let outputImage = filter1.imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput()
    filterImageview.image = outputImage
```

Now I am trying to detect the points so that i can create a separate layer for drawing within the closed boundaries..

- For example 1. orgnl image 2. filtered sobelEdgeDetection/GPUImageCannyEdgeDetectionFilter image

  1. [image]   2. [image]

  I am drawing color using pen tool.
  If I am coloring inside the circle while coloring, it should not come out of the circle boundary until I choose another touchpoints..

  Based on touch point I want to color it within closed boundaries.

I also have tried Floodfill algorithm. It gives the different output. Not exactly my desired output.

How could I apply it?

Answer (score 3):

Hey Pradip you are looking for **floodfill** algorithm  to be exact it will solve your problem.

**Floodfill Algorithm Brief Explanation -**

The flood-fill algorithm takes three parameters: a start node, a target color, and a replacement color. The algorithm looks for all nodes in the array that are connected to the start node by a path of the target color and changes them to the replacement color.

**Links for you R&D  and also a demo in obejective-c.**

1. https://ilearnios.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/scanline-flood-fill-algorithm-with-or-without-tolerance-in-objective-c/
2. https://lodev.org/cgtutor/floodfill.html
3. https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill (Great demo courtesy of 
   Chintan-Dave)

   I have also used floodfill on my project just to remove background colors and found above links veryusefull.
   Hope it Helps

Comment: I already tried this one before.. It autofill the  wholebounded region with selected color at a time but my requirement is  different , I want to  draw color it by pen or pencil and once  i try to draw outside the bounded region no any color  should draw..

Comment: @PRADIPKUMAR ok I think i got the question , the thing is there is  one option which I can think of now.
1. if you can convert that image into bezierpath then you can check if the point is inside the path or not and draw accordingly.