# How to fill the colored part of UIView with different colors or images in swift4

Tags: ios, swift

The previous explanation was muddled up and rewritten. - 2019.07.23

1. I have two **UIView** named *MainView, CanvasView.*
2. *MainView, CanvasView* have the same frame, and More precisely, there is *CanvasView* on *MainView*.
3. Using **UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext**, I colored a certain area for *CanvasView*.

Next, I want to fill the *MainView*'s area just like an uncoloured area of *CanvasView* with different colors or images like photoshop feature filling selected areas or fill other areas.

- Example - simple scenario

  1. [draw purple color on canvasView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5wUR.png)
  2. [fill an uncolored area with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvrxU.png)
  3. [Get the MainView like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U0wa.png)

Comment: Please mention what you have tried and where you stuck. Please edit the question and add such details.

Comment: go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553432/how-can-i-colour-my-sketch-using-pen-tool-within-the-limited-edge-boundaries-usi/52586986#52586986 , I think you are looking for something like this.

Comment: This may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160229/how-to-get-the-color-of-a-pixel-in-an-uiview

Comment: @Kampai I'm sorry that the explanation is not good. Currently, I'm thinking of using the UIView's pixels to solve.

Comment: @ShivamGaur Thank you ! I didn't know there was an algorithm like this. It's very similar to what I've been looking for.