# iOS - How to fill color in Prescribed area

Tags: ios, swift

when I touch **one place**,Within the Prescribed area fill the green color.like this:

[image: like this]

and this:
[image]

click one of the fish，the both fish are red

Now I can only use the scan line seed filling algorithm to identify a closed area, but cannot identify multiple areas。

Like this coral, *one click* fills in multiple areas

if any one gives solution it would be so great,Thank you. (English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.)

### -----------------------------------------------------------

I have a crude idea.

1. First find two seed points on the ear(A and B).
2. Click on the picture, if you find that the stack contains seed point A， calling method  `floodFill(from: B)` continue

but I don't konw how to implementation `if you find that the stack contains seed point A` in this [demo](https://github.com/lkkwxy/PaintImageView)

[image: img]

Comment: Use Paint Bucket library.

Comment: Could you send me a link? I didn't find it   @dahiya_boy

Comment: https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill for floodfill which is one method. https://github.com/jflinter/PaintBucket is paintbucket as @dahiya_boy mentioned

Comment: thaks for your link , but it didn't work for me. Because the picture only one click.

Comment: go through, this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553432/how-can-i-colour-my-sketch-using-pen-tool-within-the-limited-edge-boundaries-usi/52586986#52586986

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have solved the problem, this is a **[Demo](https://github.com/make1a/PaintImageView)**

This solution requires fixing two seed points on the leaves。
When a seed point is triggered for coloring, The other one is also coloring.
[image: show]

**If there's a better solution, let me know please.**

Comment: Hello make, please check below url
https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill